# Select removes hover state in parent

Tags: html, css

I have a container with some info and a select input. This container opens when you hover over it's parent container. My problem is that in IE and Chrome beta (not too worried about Chrome beta), whenever I try to open the select, the container loses focus and closes.

Check this fiddle: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/txL957f4/)**

```
<ul class="hover">
    <a href="#">Some title</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-container">
        <li>
            <select>Select label
                <option>item 1</option>
                <option>item 2</option>
                <option>item 3</option>
            </select>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

So I'm wondering if anybody out there has a clever trick or fix for this.

/*** EDIT ***/

So I managed to work around this issue to some extent. It's not perfect but it works. Any improvements you can think of are welcome but for now this is my solution.

```
var listDropdown = $('.cp-listDropdown');
    var dropdownContent = $('.cp-dropdown-content');

    listDropdown.on("mouseover", function () {
        dropdownContent.css('visibility', 'visible');
    }).on("mouseout", function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
           var isHovered = listDropdown.is(':hover');
           if (!isHovered) {
               dropdownContent.css('visibility', 'hidden');
           }
        }, 1500);
    });
```

Comment: I can't use click, it must be on hover.

Comment: use javascript, I recommend jQuery function toggle: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I've tried jQuery but the problem stays the same. As soon as the parent loses focus it closes.

Comment: and you must use hover?

Comment: Yes. That is the only requirement.